# Testing external "C" callback function from Rust

Tags: rust

I'm looking at a C API written with Rust and are using callback functions. The implementation pattern looks like this

```
type FooCallback = extern "C" fn(data: &FooData, context: FooContext);

trait FooCallbackExt {
    fn call(&self, data: FooData, context: FooContext);
}

impl FooCallbackExt for FooCallback {
    fn call(&self, data_in: FooData, context: FooContext) {
        // Doing cool things
    }
}
```

I can test this from the C-side by creating a callback function like this:

```
void callback(const FooData* data, FooContext context)
```

Now I would like to test this interface from the Rust-side as well, as close as possible to the exposed C interface, to isolate an issue that I believe is happening in Rust.

The Rust function taking this data looks like this:
`fn foo(&mut self, callback: FooCallback, context: FooContext)` but I'm confused about how how to create a callback from the Rust side.

Do I need to create some type of converter or layer in-between? Or can I create a Rust type-version of the callback but have them both use the same trait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create a callback function like that in Rust like so:

```
extern "C" fn bar(data: &FooData, context: FooContext) {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: Ofc! That works! Is there a way for me to reuse the type `FooCallback` somehow?

Comment: @munger When defining it? Not that I'm aware of unfortunately. Though it will obviously be type-checked when passing it to `foo`.

Comment: Hmm, then there is a missing piece in that the trait `call` is implemented for that type, but it is not if create a callback function like above.

Comment: @munger depending on what you're trying, you may need to coerce it to `FooCallback` first. Technically all Rust functions are unique types. Try `(bar as FooCallback).call()`. If you pass it to `foo`, it will do that for you.